# Ansible lineinfile replace with system variable

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook, configuration-management, devops

I'm encountering an issue while using Ansible to dynamically modify a Zabbix agent configuration file. Specifically, I'm attempting to employ an ansible lineinfile module with a loop to update multiple lines within the file.

The script effectively changes values within the file, but I'm facing a syntax error when attempting to incorporate a variable into the Zabbix agent configuration. The objective is to replace the line "Hostname=Zabbix Server" with "Hostname=$HOSTNAME", allowing the value to be automatically sourced from the target machine. For instance, if the computer name is "computer1", the agent file should reflect "Hostname=computer1".

Below is the relevant snippet of my current lineinfile code:

```
 - name: Update Zabbix Agent Configuration
   ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
  loop:
    - { regexp: '^Server=', line: 'Server=monlocal.xyz.com' }
    - { regexp: '^ServerActive=', line: 'ServerActive=monlocal.xyz.com' }
    - { regexp: '^Hostname=', line: 'Hostname={{ ansible_facts['hostname'] }}' }
```

here is the error I get.

```
The offending line appears to be:

        - { regexp: '^ServerActive=', line: 'ServerActive=monlocal.xyz.com' }
                                  ^ here

There appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

I know the error is with the 3rd line. when I remove the 3rd line I get the expected result.
any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yousuf

Comment: Did you try the suggestion? (replacing the single quotes `'` surrounding your variable with double quotes `"'`)

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I made some adjustments to the script:
Initially, the script requested to add a section. I included "Section" in the task details, but the Zabbix agent configuration file doesn't contain a section. The output now displays as follows.
Moreover, investory_hostname is printing only local IP address and not hostname
any idea will be very of great help.
now the output is like 

[General]
Server:  zabbix.example.com
ServerActive: zabbix.example.com
hostname : 192.168.x.x

So how can i deal with Section when there is no section in the file and IP to hostname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [default Zabbix Agent Config file](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/conf/zabbix_agentd.conf) is an INI file with just

```ini
LogFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.log
Server=127.0.0.1
ServerActive=127.0.0.1
Hostname=Zabbix server
```

an minimal example playbook with [`ini_file` module – Tweak settings in INI files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html#examples)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - ini_file:
      path: zabbix_agentd.conf
      option: "{{ item.option }}"
      value: "{{ item.value }}"
    loop:
      - { option: 'Server', value: 'zabbix.example.com' }
      - { option: 'ServerActive', value: 'zabbix.example.com' }
      - { option: 'Hostname', value: '{{ inventory_hostname }}' }
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [ini_file] ****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={u'option': u'Server', u'value': u'zabbix.example.com'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={u'option': u'ServerActive', u'value': u'zabbix.example.com'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={u'option': u'Hostname', u'value': u'localhost'})
```

and a changed configuration file with

```ini
LogFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.log
Server = zabbix.example.com
ServerActive = zabbix.example.com
Hostname = localhost
```

So there is absolute no need for "editing" the file with lineinfile and Regular Expressions.

Comment: I made some adjustments to the script: Initially, the script requested to add a section. I included "Section" in the task details, but the Zabbix agent configuration file doesn't contain a section. The output now displays as follows. Moreover, investory_hostname is printing only local IP address and not hostname any idea will be very of great help. now the output is like [General] Server: zabbix.example.com ServerActive: zabbix.example.com hostname : 192.168.x.x So how can i deal with Section when there is no section in the file and IP to hostname